# How can I automatically start NGINX when server starts?

Tags: nginx

I have two sites running on two Linode servers.

When I restart server #1, it automatically starts NGINX again right away

When I restart server #2, it does not!

How can I configure my server so that it restarts NGINX when I reboot the server?

Thanks in advance...

Bo

Comment: how you have installed nginx? which os? does apache is also installed?

Comment: Do you use systemd?

Answer (score 1):

Put in /etc/rc.local:

```
/www/nginx/sbin/nginx (or what you path is)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using ubuntu you can use update-rc.d

```
update-rc.d nginx enable 2345
```

or if your using a redhat based system

```
chkconfig nginx --level 2345 on
```